# Replacing content of a div using Ajax callback function in a webpart page

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-addin, ajax, html

In a sharePoint web part, I have a div for which I am loading content dynamically by doing something like

```
$("#divID1").load('/sites/somesite/WikiPages/abc.aspx.ms-rte-layoutszone-inner.html();
```

to get wiki page data.

And this is pretty much working fine but I now want to trim this divID1 content. 
For which I have tried things like

```
$("#divID1").load('/sites/somesite/Pages/abc.aspx.ms-rte-layoutszone-inner.html', function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
alert(responseTxt);
});
```

I have tried using this too

```
$.get( '/sites/somesite/WikiPages/abc.aspx #divID1 > *', function( data ) {
alert(data);
});
```

The problem which I am facing is that I am only able to retrieve html content from the above functions, not plain string. Whereas I need to get the string which was loaded in divID1 tag and trim it and then replace the divID1 tag content with the trimmed string. I have been trying this since a day or more. Can somebody show me the way out of this trouble?

Comment: Why don't you try [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function, once successful trim and load your div ?

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri This is what I did `$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '/sites/somesite/Pages/'+tn+' .ms-rte-layoutszone-inner',
    error: function(xhr, status, error) { alert('Error: '+ xhr.status+ ' - '+ error); },
    success: function(response) {}
    });` But in the url parameter it is not giving the required div content. Any suggestions how can I take a particular div content from that specified url. I need to mention in div only since on mentioning the div class in success handler it runs into a stack overflow.